# Postgres is there a way to simplify my where clause without using unnest and string_to_array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-9.6

The following SQL works for me and gives me the results I want:

```
select postdomain from post where postdomain not in (select unnest (string_to_array('youtube.com|twitter.com' , '|'))) ;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to simply the `where` part?

For example, if I don't want exact match and need a case-insensitive `contains` match, this simpler SQL works without the unnest and string_to_array stuff:

```
select postdomain from post where postdomain !~* 'youtube.com|twitter.com' ;
```

Is there a way to achieve the exact match similarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an unnest, you can use the array directly:

```
select postdomain 
from post 
where postdomain <> ALL (string_to_array('youtube.com|twitter.com' , '|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor the pattern:

```
where postdomain !~* '^youtube.com$|^twitter.com$'
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` the end.

Comment: Is there no easy operator which doesn't involve me having to alter the delimited string?

Comment: Yes, there is; see the other answer.